# how can i get user object in comment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to get the post with the user,and posts comments but i also want commented user data. currently i'm getting userdata and comments related to post with this code but also want user object for comments. the code i'm using is in **PostController.php**

```
public function index()
{   
    $post=Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('user')->with('comments' )->get();
    return response()->json(["posts" => $post ]);
}
```

this is returning

[image]

i also set the relationship in models
**is there any way i can get user object inside comments object like this:**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set up the same user relationship inside of your comment model, then use `with(['comments', 'comments.user'])`

Comment: Hi Thanks! it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
public function index()
{   
    $post = Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')with(['comments', 'comments.user'])->get();
    return response()->json(["posts" => $post ]);
}
```

i hope help you

Comment: Yes Thanks! @aynber suggest the same and its working fine :)